# MySQL - query by number or letter?

Tags: mysql

I need to set values to a `"Yes or No"` column name `STATUS`. And I'm thinking about 2 methods.

method 1 (use letter): set value `Y/N` then find all rows that have value `Y` in field `STATUS` by a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE status="Y"
```

method 2 (use number): set value `1/0` then find all rows that have value `1` in field `STATUS` by a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE status=1
```

Should I use method 1 or method 2? Which one is faster? Which one is better?

Comment: Don't use either of them since they are both semantically incorrect, a status can't be Yes or No. If you for example need to know if a post is published, use is_published as a boolean.

Comment: @Peter . . . Actually, if that is the purpose, then don't use a flag at all.  Just keep a `PublishedDate` and check whether or not it is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are essentially equivalent, so this becomes a question of which is better for your application.

If you are concerned about space, then the smallest space for one character is `char(1)`, using 8 bits.  With a number, you can use bit or set types for pack multiple flags.  But, this only makes a difference if you have lots of flags.

The store-it-as-a-number approach has a slight advantage, where you can count the "Yes" values by doing:

```
select sum(status)
```

(Of course, in MySQL, this is only a marginal improvement on `sum(status = 'Y')`.

The store-it-as-a-letter approach has a slight advantage if you decide to include "Maybe" or other values at some point in the future.

Finally, any difference in performance in different ways of representing these values is going to be very, very minimal.  You would need a table with millions and millions of rows to start to notice a problem.  So, use the mechanism that works best for your application and way of representing the value.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way would be **;**

```
 SELECT * FROM post WHERE `status` = FIND_IN_SET(`status`,'y');
```

I think you should create column with `ENUM('n','y')`. Mysql stores this type in optimal way. It also will help you to store only allowed values in the field.

You can also make it more human friendly ENUM('no','yes') without affect to performance. Because strings 'no' and 'yes' are stored only once per ENUM definition. Mysql stores only index of the value per row.

Answer (score 0):

Second one is definitely faster primarily because whenever you involve something within quotes , it is meaningless to SQL.   It would be better to use types that are non string in order to get better performance.  I would suggest using METHOD 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method 1 is better if you are concerned with the storage prospective .
As storing an integer i.e  1/2  takes 4 bytes of memory where as a character takes only 1 byte of memory. So its better to use method 1.
This may increase some performance .